# What are the possible channels and methods for sharing content with only one person from an iPhone app?

Tags: iphone, ios, social-media, sharing

I'm working on an iPhone app that will allow users to create a "book" and share it with a friend. For the most part, I anticipate users will only share each book with one person.

It seems most sharing is done by broadcasting to everyone (Facebook feed, Twitter), but that's not what this app is for. What are some possible channels and methods for sharing content with only one person from an iPhone app?

Comment: That's what I don't like about iOS. Android has a standardized "share" action and then the user gets to choose which app to use in sharing.

Answer (score 4):

**E-mail** is the ever-present and most used channel for 1-to-1 communications (instant messaging may be rivaling it in some cases). However, it may not be your solution as you don't know yet who is going to be the primary user of this application. Those people may have completely different workflows and/or channel preferences. Do some user research around this and you'll have a much better answer.

Comment: Email and iMessage/SMS seem to be the strongest choices. I've updated my question a bit to reflect my intention. I'm really looking for all of possibilities for private sharing.

Answer (score 0):

What about a custom implementation of iTunes File sharing?
http://www.raywenderlich.com/1948/how-integrate-itunes-file-sharing-with-your-ios-app

I couldn't tell if it was desktop to device only or if you could do device to device...

A similar concept with images and email implementation:
http://appsjam.com/2011/05/19/private-image-sharing-now-available-on-your-ios-with-sneak-a-peek/

This article mentions more private based sharing options, including Dropbox:
http://www.archicadwiki.com/BIMx/iOStransfer